# How can Create File on Automation test in android studio

Tags: android-studio, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I want to UI Automation test for creating PDF File but below error shown. It can't find the storage path to can save file

androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 358, 1078 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id is com.example.firsttest:id/CreatePDF'.

It works when run code as an app, but when run as an automation test not work.

Comment: Could you share the code for the Test along with the code the the Activity or Fragment where the test should be executed on? That would make it easier to pinpoint what is the problem with the Test.

Comment: it's working now, Thank you so much, your answer gives me a hint to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Espresso is not able to find a View with id CreatePDF on the visible screen on which to execute the Click, hence the error stating that `Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 358, 1078 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id is com.example.firsttest:id/CreatePDF'`

If you are sure that the Test is being executed on the correct screen, check if you have disabled Animations on the device on which the test is being executed, otherwise Espresso might execute the Test while the animations are still running and it is unable to find the mentioned View. You can check how to disable the animations on the device in the [Espresso documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup)

If that is not the case, then it could be the case that the Test is being executed over a previous Activity, Fragment or View where the CreatePDF View is not yet visible.